# Synonymize [intellij-idea-14]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

There seem to be duplicate tags for *IntelliJ Idea 14*

[intellij-14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-14) and [intellij-idea-14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea-14), with 150-ish and 80-ish questions respectively.

It looks like they should be made into synonyms.

Comment: This is done now : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340965/merge-tags-intellij-idea-14-and-intellij-14