# Merge tags [intellij-idea-14] and [intellij-14]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Looks like the two tags [intellij-14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-14) and [intellij-idea-14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea-14) can be merged together, since they are about the same technology.

Alternatively, we could simply remove the [intellij-idea-14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea-14) tag, which has a less-complete tag wiki.

Looks like this was already requested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290661/synonymize-intellij-idea-14), but it doesn't appear anyone did anything about it.

Comment: Merging and creating a synonym is the right thing to do. We'll need a moderator to do it. Presumably you'd vote for [intellij-14] being the "master" tag, right?

Comment: I'd actually more go for Intellij-idea-14 in this case, given that that's the proper product title. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: True, but for consistency [tag:intellij-14] might be better, as there are a lot of other tags of the form `intellij-N` where `N` is the version number/name:  [tag:intellij-10] [tag:intellij-12] [tag:intellij-13] [tag:intellij-14] [tag:intellij-15] [tag:intellij-16]

Comment: @GreenGiant Good point, consistency is better.

Answer (score 6):

Well, [look who became a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340965/merge-tags-intellij-idea-14-and-intellij-14#comment429084_340965) :-)

This is now done:

- [intellij-14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-14) ← [intellij-idea-14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea-14)
- [intellij-15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-15) ← [intellij-idea-15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea-15)

The `[intellij-*]` variant was used as the master tag because it predominated among the existing version-specific tags and thus appears to be the community's preference, as was pointed out previously.

Comment: Weird bump by community. On the topic of merging these tags, people keep making wonky tags like [tag:intellij-idea-2016] and [tag:intellij-idea2017] ...

Comment: @Gimby Community periodically bumps questions that are unanswered, or questions with zero-score answers. This one was zero-scored before it was bumped. Not really that weird. What would be the correct/master tags for those that you mentioned?

Comment: Please note that IDEA versions are called 2017 and 2016 now, but previously it was 13, 14, 15. They changed naming scheme.

Comment: Well, there goes the consistency then :)